# permissions in flex/Action script

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, mxml, mxmlc

I have two applications which access camera and mic written in flex.When these two resources had to be used it ask `flash player asks for the use of system resource Allow or Deny` Is there any way to by pass this.In gmail->settings->chat->view settings it doesnt ask for this confirmation.How to code this

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to bypass this dialog. I couldn't find the gmail feature you were referring to, but I highly doubt that they have some way of working around this security barrier.

Comment: Doesn't matter, it's still a matter of security and cannot be bypassed. For more information on the settings panel, visit: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help09.html

Comment: How does gmail make it possible in this case

Comment: I don't know, I couldn't verify because I don't have those settings in gmail at all. It's possible that you have set it to always allow access in that particular instance, but there's still no way to get around that first dialog promt. Instead, you should educate your users.

Comment: You would not get that option when using a RHEL flavour.Have u tried it on a  windows machine.Also it would be activated if u dont have a webcam.So u can try on a windows laptop with webcam